# Issue while Upload file using Multipart Request in Codename One

Tags: java, codenameone

I tried to upload a image to the server, it throws me the Error 405 : Method not found, but from that same Url i can able to Download any files.. following is the code i tried.

```
 private void uploadFileToServer(ActionEvent event) throws IOException
{
    try{
        InfiniteProgress ip = new InfiniteProgress();
        Dialog dlg = ip.showInifiniteBlocking();
        dlg.show();

        MultipartRequest request = new MultipartRequest();
        FileSystemStorage fs = FileSystemStorage.getInstance();
        String fileUri = fs.getAppHomePath() + "654319032015150536IR.png";

        request.setUrl("http://192.XX.XX.58:XX/HttpFolder/");
        request.setPost(true);

        InputStream is = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openInputStream(fileUri);
        request.addData("file", is, FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getLength(fileUri), "image/png");
        request.setFilename("file", fileUri);
        request.setPriority(ConnectionRequest.PRIORITY_CRITICAL);
        NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(request);
        dlg.dispose();

        if (event instanceof NetworkEvent) {
            NetworkEvent ne = (NetworkEvent)event;
            Dialog.show("Result:", ne.getMetaData().toString(), "","");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Dialog.show("ERROR", e.getMessage(), "OK",null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't upload to an arbitrary URL, you need to have a servlet that handles multipart on the `POST` http method.

We have a demo that includes the server side code here: http://codenameone.com/blog/build-mobile-ios-apps-in-java-using-codename-one-on-youtube.html

Notice that you also did some other "problematic" things in the code such as using `PRIORITY_CRITICAL` and using the InputStream API rather than just giving the file URL (which is more efficient).